# Python Turtle Image Placement

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, turtle-graphics

Does anyone know how i would put a gif image  over a [turtle created background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e0eK.png).  This is the grid layout that was created in a array:

```
pixels =     [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

pixels.append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

I can't get the gif images to appear above the grid. The grid is a background and [a pixel soldier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thyrl.gif) would appear above the grid.

I am using the Turtle library and cannot use the pygame library

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of putting an image above a turtle-drawn background.  I used my own grid code, since you didn't provide yours, but it could be anything drawn by the turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

N = 10  # N by N grid
LENGTH = 30  # each grid element will be LENGTH x LENGTH pixels

def grid(turtle, n, length):
    sign = 1
    for _ in range(2):

        for _ in range(n):
            turtle.forward(length * n)
            turtle.left(sign * 90)
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.left(sign * 90)
            sign = 0 - sign

        turtle.forward(length * n)
        [turtle.right, turtle.left][n % 2](90)
        sign = 0 - sign

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience
screen.register_shape("Thyrl.gif")

background = Turtle()
background.hideturtle()

background.penup()
background.goto(-N * LENGTH/2, screen.window_height()/2 - N * LENGTH)
background.pendown()

grid(background, N, LENGTH)

foreground = Turtle("Thyrl.gif")
foreground.penup()
foreground.sety(screen.window_height()/2 - N * LENGTH/2)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

The image needs a transparent background for this to come out cleanly.  I also shrank your image to make the pixels normal size.